# All science journal classification (code and name) from pybliometrics, how to retrieve this info from the API

Tags: scopus, pybliometrics

I have a list of EIDs linked to Scopus authors ids,  I’ve been trying to retrieve the **all science journal classification(code and name)** from each article but I cannot find in the pybliometrics documentation the way to do it.
I would appreciate some help about this!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Abstract Retrieval does not provide this information, which is frequent, use the Serial Title API for workaround:

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import AbstractRetrieval, SerialTitle

ab = AbstractRetrieval("2-s2.0-85068268027")
s = SerialTitle(ab.issn)
print(s.subject_area)
```

You get a list of namedtuples:

```
[Subjectarea(area='Software', abbreviation='COMP', code='1712'),
 Subjectarea(area='Computer Science Applications', abbreviation='COMP', code='1706')]
```

Unfortunately, the Serial Title API expects ISSNs. They are sometimes missing, occasionally wrong, and not necessarily stable. Scopus updates them twice a year.

If the ISSN is missing, try searching for the Serial (= the source) with the `SerialSearch()` class:

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import AbstractRetrieval, SerialSearch

ab = AbstractRetrieval("2-s2.0-85068268027")
s = SerialSearch({"title": ab.publicationName})
```

What you need would be in `s.results` - it can be a very long list of tuples as it contains all kinds of source metrics.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. It would be great if in the future  this information will be included in the **documents** results.